# How to attach outlet box in soffit?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, soffit

I'm now planning to install out outlet flush, or as flush/above as possible, to the soffit.

I've read other threads, and believe I'm good on how to protect it, etc.

I buy a rate outside box correct? Then I cut a hole that's (guessing) the same size as box? If so how does the box get mounted/attached? Or do I get a regular box and use the regular nails, and then get a waterproof in use cover?

Comment: I do not intend to be mean, but I have to ask you a question. Do you have any experience wiring electrical devices? I don't want you to get hurt or burn down your house. The nature of your questions leads me to believe you don't have much experience.  If you feel confident to wire this safely, I can lay out a weather proof combo for ya. Yes, you need a weatherproof box, flange mounted with a matching weatherproof cover. If you are using a receptacle, you will need to use a GFi with matching cover.

Comment: Am I missing something.. Why does an outlet in a soffit need to be waterproof?

Comment: NM i guess it is a roof soffit you are talking about. What type of soffit is it?  vinyl,plywood?

Comment: @JustinK The soffit is considered a damp/wet location, and so a weatherproof installation is appropriate.

Comment: Ya I know I was thinking of an inside soffit.

Answer (score 2):

It's going to depend on what material is covering the soffit.

## Soffit Covers

If it's aluminium/plastic soffit covers, you'll have to remove the section where you're installing the receptacle.  Install proper bracing (a simple 2x4 between the rafters should be fine), and attach the electrical box to it. Then mark, and cut a hole for the electrical box in the soffit cover. Finish by putting the soffit cover back in place.

Make sure to measure and align the box properly, so the box will be flush with (or just protruding from) the soffit cover.

## Wood

If it's wood, you can either surface, or flush mount the electrical box. Simply select the appropriate box for your installation.

## Weatherproofing and Ground-fault protection

Because the receptacle is outside, you'll want to provide ground-fault protection.  You'll also want to make sure the box, and cover are both weatherproof and approved for damp/wet locations. See [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/28398/33), to the question [How do I install a receptacle in the soffit?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/28396/33) for more information.

Comment: I like the flush mounts with the ears on the side of the box for the mounting screws in firm materials.  They seem to work well.

Comment: I should also add, that if he plans to use a duplex receptacle, it must be a GFIC since it is accessible from outdoors.